# Connecting multiple post types? Or linking "News" posts with "Game" posts how?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I am building gaming news and tutorial website. But i don't know how to link multiple post types with one specific post.

For example, i created post types called

```
Games
News
Tutorials
Videos
Reviews
```

So the games post type will be basically a list of Games, News will be posts with news, and Tutorials will be tutorials.

But i need to somehow link News and Tutorials to the specific post in Games post type.

Another example

In Games i have made a post with game called Counter Strike.

And when user click on that post he goes to the post and reads basic info of the game i inserted when i made that post.

But i have a menu where i put

```
News
Tutorials
Videos
Reviews
```

So when he click on News, the visitor need to have all the posts from news custom post type related to the game from Game post and have them listed all.

Here is a screenshot

[image: this is custom post types]

[image: post inside games custom post type]

This is a post that i made inside Games custom post type and as you can see its basically a post with informations of the game.

But this menu with news, reviews, guides... when i click on news i need to get somehow a list of all the posts from news, related to counter strike game(post) in Games.

A way to do this?

Custom category or taxonomy and link them?

Comment: Never used it but check out https://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-to-posts/. It's well regarded and I think will do what you need.

Comment: From what i seen on plugin page this might help, ill go and install it and check out what i can do with a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to setup categories / sub categories.

Example:

1. News

   - Counter-Strike
   - StartCraft2

and link them together that way. This will (I believe) especially be much easier when querying your posts, so that you can query from a specific category (ie: Counter-Strike News)

Comment: I was thinking something like that, just other way around. Each game have it's own category and sub category news tutorials etc... just im not sure how would i link that into one post.

Comment: you're better off dropping the 'games' custom post type, and making each game a 'category'. then you could create custom post types for 'news', 'tutorials', 'reviews', etc...and then assigning the new content / post to a category (game)

Comment: i was thinking about that too stoopkid1 but than i have to make that "game" categori a bit different and fill up with some info like tags, release date, screenshot... which will make it really hard to do if it's category.